# Piranha CMS Menu items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, piranha-cms

Trying to add some new menu items as per [here](http://piranhacms.org/docs/extend/manager-menu) with the following code:

```
private void Add_MenuGroup()
{
    Manager.Menu.Add(new Manager.MenuGroup()
    {
        InternalId = "HireModules",
        Name = "Hire Modules",
        CssClass = "fancy-icon"
    });
}

private void Add_MenuItems()
{
    Manager.Menu.Where(m => m.InternalId == "HireModules").Single().Items.Add(
       new Manager.MenuItem()
       {
           Name = "Products",
           Action = "productlist",
           Controller = "products",
           Permission = "ADMIN_PRODUCT",
           SelectedActions = "productlist,productedit"
       });
}
```

The calls to these methods are in the Global.asax.cs and are being called without error but no new items are being added. How do I fix this?

I can see the items in the list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify an existing controller

Answer (score 0):

The example uses a custom permission, "ADMIN_PRODUCTS" that doesn't exist in your database. That's why the items are not showing. Remove the permission or add it in the manager interface!